# In Sql Server Design a database table in which Column3 = Column1 + Column2

Tags: sql, sql-server

In Sql Server Design a database table in which Column3 = Column1 + Column2, we are not allowed to use any logic (triggers, function) what all we can do during design time

Answer (score 4):

Use a computed column:

```
alter table t add column3 as (column1 + column2)
```

You could also use a view.